# Task Schedular Giving Error while scheduling R Script for saving PDF

Tags: r

I am scheduling R script which contains ggsave for saving pdf.
my code is running but on the line of `ggsave("plot.pdf)`, it is skipping code. But instead of saving pdf if i use png format then it is fine. but only for pdf it is giving problem.
Below is my sample code.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(data.table)
    a <- data.frame(a = c(1:5))
    p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5), aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
    fwrite(a,"abc1.csv")
    ggsave("plot.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `ggsave(p, "plot.pdf", device = "pdf")` work?  You may not have been specifying the plot to be saved or perhaps it doesn't know to export as pdf from only the file path that you gave?

EDIT: It should be `ggsave("plot.pdf", p, device = "pdf")` so that the arguments are in the correct order.

Comment: `ggsave("plot.pdf", p)`  I think the arguments are meant to be the other way around